# filtering values (php + jquery)

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem and hope someone with more experience can help me.

I have a table with the following fields and their values​​:

id  |  types  |  colors
----|---------|--------
1   |  pant  |  blue
2   |  pant  |  green
3   |  pant  |  red
4   |  shirt |  brow
5   |  shirt |  pink
6   |  shirt |  red

What I'm trying to do is filter out the colors according to the type of clothing chosen.

example:
If I select only the checkbox "pants", then returned values​​'' blue, green, red. "
If I select only the checkbox "shirt", then returned values​​'' brown, pink, red. "
But now I want to select the two checkboxes and I want the result to be "blue, brown, green, pink, red."

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Note: my language is not English, so excuse me if there are errors.

***Files used:***

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Checkbox</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input[name='type']").click('change', function() {
                    $("#colors").html('Loading colors...');
                    $.post("colors.php", {type: $(this).val()}, function(valor) {
                        $("#colors").html(valor);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php require_once './types.php'; ?></p>
        <p id="colors"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

*types.php*

```
<?php

require_once './connection.php';

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT types FROM test";
$con = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($con) === 0) {
    echo '0 result(s)';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($con)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="' . $row['types'] . '"> ' . $row['types'];
    }
}

?>
```

*colors.php*

```
<?php

require_once './connection.php';

$type = $_POST['type'];

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT colors FROM test WHERE types = '$type'";
$con = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($con) === 0) {
    echo '0 result(s)';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($con)) {
        echo $row['colors'] . '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your checkbox `type[]`, this will allow you to get an array of types.

Then adjust your colour query to this:

```
$types = "'".implode("','",array_map("mysql_real_escape_string",$_POST['type']))."'";
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `colors` FROM `test` WHERE `types` IN (".$types.")";
```

Comment: Wow, a response at the speed of light. Thanks for the help my friend.